# PHP/HTML submit redirection to 404 not found

Tags: php, html, web

I'm creating a simple web app that calculates the age of when you're going to graduate. My program runs fine in eclipse but as soon as I push it to the server and push my button (submit) it redirects to a 404 error. I'm using ipages and I'm aware that they are using php 5.6. Any helpful tips would help out a ton.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Graduation Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<img alt="Image goes here..." src="Balloon-Banner.jpg" width = "1050" height="180">

<form action="grad.php" method="POST">
<center>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<label><?php echo "Today is " . date("m/d/Y"); ?></label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Enter your birth year: </label>
    <input type="text" name="birthYear" />

    <label>Enter your graduation year: </label>
    <input type="text" name="gradYear" />
    <br>
    <label>Enter your Birth Month: </label>
    <input type = "text" name = "birthMonth"/>
    <label> Enter your graduation month</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "gradmonth" />
    <br>
    <label> Enter your birthday</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "birthDay" />
    <label>Enter your graduation day: </label>
    <input type="text" name="gradday" />
    <br>
    <input type='submit' value='Graduation Age' id = 'submit' />
    </center>
</form>


<?php

$submitted = ! empty ( $_POST );

if ($submitted == true)
{

    $bYear = (int) $_POST ['birthYear'];
    $gYear  = (int) $_POST ['gradYear'];
    $gMonth = (int) $_POST['gradmonth'];
    $bMonth = (int) $_POST['birthMonth'];
    $bday = (int) $_POST['birthDay'];
    $gday = (int) $_POST ['gradday'];



    $age = getAge($bYear, $gYear, $bMonth, $gMonth, $bday, $gday);
    if($age!= NULL){
        echo "You will be " . $age . " at your graduation.";
    }
    else{
        echo "INVALID INPUT, PLEASE TRY AGAIN";
    }


}
function getAge( $bYear,  $gYear, $bMonth, $gMonth, $bday, $gday)
{
    If($bYear> $gYear || $bMonth>12 || $gMonth >12 || $bday >31 || $gday >31 || $bYear == 0 || $gYear == 0 || $bMonth == 0 || $bday == 0 || $gMonth ==0|| $gday == 0){
        return NULL;
    }
    $age = $gYear - $bYear;

    if($bMonth == $gMonth){

        if($bday <= $gday){

            return $age;
        }
        else{

            $age = $age-1;
            return $age;
        }
    }
        elseif($bMonth < $gMonth){

            return $age;
        }
        else{
            return $age-1;
        }
        return $age;
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When dealing with external hosters, the best way to proceed is to build an Apache - PHP server with the same version they use.  This way you can test with a certain level or certainty.  Also, if you name your file grad.php, did you configure iPages to understand that .php should be interpretted as such?  I think I remember needing to add a config in .htaccess for that.  That is more ipage support than SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're executing your front-end and back-end code in the same file, just keep it simple and just do it in the same file unless you have a framework.

Change `<form action="grad.php" method="POST">` to `<form method="POST">`.

Should work, if not we'll try to work something out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `action="grad.php"` from form. So it will submit to self.